# Multidimensional array => CSV export in CakePHP

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, csv, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to export data from my model and two related models into a CSV file in my CakePHP 2.4 app, and need some help doing it in a computationally non-expensive manner.

In my app, each `Post hasMany Field` and each `Field belongsTo Fieldtype.` `Fields` stores values, and `Fieldtype` stores the value types (IE "Oxygen concentration"). On each `Post`, there can be multiple `Fields` with the same `Fieldtype.`

The problem with CSV generation here is that each Post's Fields require a different number of columns, so when I'm doing my `fputcsv` I'm going to need to add empty cells for when any `Post` has less than the maximum number of fields for, say, Helium so the headers line up.

Is there a SQL solution that will somehow let me do a join on my Posts find and return an array of Fieldtypes with the maximum number of Fields needed for each Fieldtype?

My DB structure:

```
Posts
id

Fields
id    post_id    fieldtype_id    value

Fieldtypes
id    name
```

Comment: It sounds like your question is sql. e.g. `select posts.id, count(fields.id) from posts left join fields on () group by posts.id`. If that's not it you should improve your question: Showing what you've tried doesn't explain what you're trying to do or what end result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote my question to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find an easy way to get the field count in SQL, and as it turns out doing it in PHP isn't *too* slow because it's not like I'm accessing the database each time.

If anyone else has to deal with this problem, here's what I did:

```
//Where $posts is my array of Posts and $fieldtypes is an id => name array of my column types
public function makeCSV($posts = array(), $fieldtypes = array()){
    $fields = array();
    $fieldlist = array();
    foreach($posts as $post){
        foreach($post['Field'] as $field){
            if($field['value'] != ''){
                $fields[] = $field['fieldtype_id'];
                $fieldlist[$field['fieldtype_id']] = null;
            }
        } //Get a list of all the fields for that post

        $postcount = array_count_values($fields);
        $fields = array();

        // get a per-post count of fields

        foreach($postcount as $id => $count){
            if ($count > $fieldlist[$id] || !isset($fieldlist[$id])){
                $fieldlist[$id] = $count;
            }
        }
    }

        $output = null;     
        $output .= "Latitude" . ",";
        $output .= "Longitude" . ",";
        $output .= "Sighted (UTC)" . ",";
        $output .= "Posted (UTC)" . ",";
        $output .= "User" . ",";
        $output .= "Location" . ",";
        $output .= "Tags" . ",";
        $output .= "Category" . ",";
        $output .= "Species status" . ",";
//      $output .= "Comments" . ",";

    foreach ($fieldlist as $fieldtype => $count){
        $total = $count;
        while($count != 0){
            $output .= $fieldtypes[$fieldtype] . " " . ($total + 1 - $count)  . ",";
            --$count;
        }
    }
        $output = $output . "\n";

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $output = $output . addslashes($post['Post']['lat']) . "," . addslashes($post['Post']['lng']) . ",";
        $output = $output . "\"" . addslashes($post['Post']['sighted']) . "\"" . ",";
        $output = $output . "\"" . addslashes($post['Post']['created']) . "\"" . ",";
        $output = $output . "\"" . addslashes($post['User']['username']) . "\"" . ",";
        $output = $output . "\"" . addslashes($post['Post']['location']) . "\"" . ",";
        $output = $output . "\"" . addslashes($post['Post']['tags']) . "\"" . ",";
        $output = $output . addslashes($post['Post']['category']) . ",";
        if ($post['Post']['status'] == 1) {
            $output .= "Present,";
        } elseif($post['Post']['status'] == 2) {
            $output .= "Recently Appeared,";
        } elseif ($post['Post']['status'] == 3) {
            $output .= "Disappeared,";
        }
        else {
            $output .= ",";
        }
//      $output = $output . "\"" . addslashes(str_replace(array("\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $post['Post']['body'])) . "\"" . ",";

        foreach ($fieldlist as $fieldtype => $count){
            foreach($post['Field'] as $field){
                if($field['fieldtype_id'] == $fieldtype){
                    $output .= $field['value'] . ",";
                    --$count;
                }
            }
            while ($count > 0){
                $output .= ",";
                --$count;
            }
        }
        $output = $output . "\n";   
    }
    return $output; 
}
```